# PIvot query for month wise sql server2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
SELECT
    RNAME,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS Mai,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct
  FROM
(Select 
RNAME,
BILLAMT,
 DATEPART(mm,DATE1) as TMonth
  from
    #temp 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(BILLAMT)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ([4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
)AS pvtMonth
```

this is my query.  am getting error in this query.

i need to show monthwise billamount for rname. pls help to find out the error.
Incorrect syntax near 'pvtMonth'.
this is the structure of table

rname |billamt |date1|
aaa   | 400     | 1-04-2014|
bbb   | 200     |23-3-2014 |
bbb   | 500     |12-04-2014|

## | 100     |1-04-2014 |

i need like this
name   |mar   | Apr
aaa    |400   | 0
bbb    |200   |500
       |  0   |100

Comment: What error are you getting? We can help better if you give more details.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'pvtMonth'.

Answer (score 0):

try this u missed **close braces** and **alias name** for the `inner query`

```
SELECT RNAME,
       [4]  AS Apr,
       [5]  AS Mai,
       [6]  AS Jun,
       [7]  AS Jul,
       [8]  AS Aug,
       [9]  AS Sep,
       [10] AS Oct
FROM   (SELECT RNAME,
               BILLAMT,
               Datepart(mm, DATE1) AS TMonth
        FROM   #temp) a -- this is what u missed
       PIVOT ( Sum(BILLAMT)
             FOR TMonth IN ([4],
                            [5],
                            [6],
                            [7],
                            [8],
                            [9],
                            [10]) )AS pvtMonth
```

Comment: it shows error if there is no month in the table. is there any way to avoid this? it should show null if there is no value. is it possible?

Comment: @Indrah - need to convert this into dynamic pivot.